# Java: Change behavior of subclasses of a single base class without extending each

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say there is a class `A`, and it implements a method `eatMuffin`. `A` has many subclasses: `AA`,`AB`,...,`AZ`, and each of these uses `A`'s implementation of `eatMuffin`. If, in a seperate library, I need `eatMuffin` to actually eat two muffins, I could technically extend `AA` to `AZ` and override `eatMuffin` for each. How can I implement this behavior in a more DRY manner?

Also, bonus points if you can point out a more concise and helpful title for this in the comments.

Comment: Also, comments like "the library you're using is poorly written" are not helpful to the discussion, because this question is specifically meant to tackle the difficult situation when one is provided with such a library.

Comment: Use Composition and have EatMuffin be part of a different class. You then can inject the desired behavior with dependency injection. To @user2418306, How is multiple inheritance part of the question?

Comment: Shifting requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Unshifted. Though, to be fair to myself, that was an original requirement. Thought it was clear with "in a separate library," but I see now that that doesn't preclude one from modifying the original library.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I propose is a Decorator.

I am assuming that `eatMuffin` is part of an interface.  Let's call it `EatsMuffins`.  Class `A` implements `eatMuffin`.

Create a class `DoubleMuffinEater` that implements `EatsMuffins` and uses composition to delegate how to eat a muffin to another implementation of `EatsMuffins`.

```
public class DoubleMuffinEater implements EatsMuffins
{
    private EatsMuffins muffinEater;
    public DoubleMuffinEater(EatsMuffins muffinEater)
    {
        this.muffinEater = muffinEater;
    }
    @Override
    public void eatMuffin()
    {
        muffinEater.eatMuffin();
        muffinEater.eatMuffin();
    }
}
```

Then this decorator class simply makes the other implementation eat a muffin twice.

This can be generalized for other operations that aren't to be disturbed.  Such methods would simply call the other implementation once, a simple delegation.

Comment: What if I need the subclasses to also eat two muffins every time they call `eatMuffin` within their code, not just when it's called externally?

Answer (score 1):

I propose Composition and dependency injection

Use Composition and have EatMuffin be part of a different class. You then can inject the desired behavior with dependency injection. For example,

```
interface Eating {
   void eat();
}

interface A {
   Eating getEating();
   void setEating(Eating eating);
   void eatMuffin() throws EatingException;
}

class DefaultA implements A {

   private Eating eating;

   @Override
   public Eating getEating() {
      return eating;
   }

   @Override
   public void setEating(Eating eating) {
      this.eating = eating;
   }

   @Override
   public void eatMuffin() throws EatingException {
      if (eating == null) {
         throw new EatingException("No eating instance");         
      }
      eating.eat();      
   }
}
```